# DFA for {any sequence of a and b, between two consecutive "b" there are maximum 3 "a"}

Tags: regular-language

I have tried to draw a deterministic finite automaton for the language  L={any sequence of a and b, between two consecutive "b" there are maximum 3 "a"}:[image]

Is it correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite. Check inputs $bababababab$ and $baabaab$.

After your edit, $baabaab$ is still not accepted.
We might suggestively name the four states $a^*$, $xb$, $xba$, $xbaa$, and $xbaaa$. Then reading $b$ should take you from any of the states to $xb$, whereas reading $a$ "moves right" by one state (except that it keeps you in $a^*$ and is "forbidden" for $xbaaa$)

Comment: Do you mean that at the states 2,3,4 "b" should go to the first state? Or did I understand it wrong?